# Mix Html-Latex parser in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, latex

I would like to parse texts which are mixed of html and latex expressions (the latter given between [...] or (...)). 
Namely, an input is an expression of the form:

```
<p>text1 <ul><li> text2 \(x=1\) </li></ul> text2 \[y=0\]</p> text3 <code>z=e</code>
```

Given this sort of input, I would like to translate the texts: `text1`, `text2`,`text3`,`text4` leaving untouched the elements between `<code>...</code>`, `\[...\]` or `\(...\)`.

I was thinking to create a parser, namely a tree which corresponds to the attached image for the given input.

[image: tree]

- First, do I need to do all that work ?
- Second, I am wondering if I should code all from scratch or if it could
  some libraries like [HTML parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html).

Comment: One idea: replace `\[...\]` with some tag, eg '<bracket>...</bracket>`, similar for `\(...\)` and use `BeautifulSoup` for parsing. At the end replace `<bracket>` to `\[...\]` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible implementation of algorithm I described in the comments:

```
data = '''<p>text1 <ul><li> text2 \(x=1\) </li></ul> text3 \[y=0\]</p> text4 <code>z=e</code>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

s = re.sub(r'\\\[', r'<bracket1>', data)
s = re.sub(r'\\\]', r'</bracket1>', s)
s = re.sub(r'\\\(', r'<bracket2>', s)
s = re.sub(r'\\\)', r'</bracket2>', s)

soup = BeautifulSoup('<mydata>' + s + '</mydata>', 'html.parser')

for t in soup.select(':not(bracket1):not(bracket2):not(code)'):
    for txt in t.find_all(text=True, recursive=False):
        if txt.strip():
            txt.replace_with("I've changed {}".format(txt))

s = str(soup)
s = re.sub(r'<bracket1>', r'\\[', s)
s = re.sub(r'</bracket1>', r'\\]', s)
s = re.sub(r'<bracket2>', r'\\(', s)
s = re.sub(r'</bracket2>', r'\\)', s)

print('Old data:', data)
print('New data:', ''.join(str(t) for t in BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser').mydata.contents))
```

Prints:

```
Old data: <p>text1 <ul><li> text2 \(x=1\) </li></ul> text3 \[y=0\]</p> text4 <code>z=e</code>
New data: <p>I've changed text1 <ul><li>I've changed  text2 \(x=1\) </li></ul>I've changed  text3 \[y=0\]</p>I've changed  text4 <code>z=e</code>
```

Comment: It's more than expected, Thanks for this idea. I am trying to deal with the error:
  File "tmp.py", line 16, in <module> for t in soup.select(':not(bracket1):not(bracket2):not(code)'):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1497, in select
    "A pseudo-class must be prefixed with a tag name.") ValueError: A pseudo-class must be prefixed with a tag name.
does it come from my installation of bs4 ?

Comment: The error is raised when the tag name is empty, see line 1252:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/code.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+/965589f22ed99bca6b3b919462f2958834c11940/bs4/element.py

Comment: @Smilia what version of bs4 are you using? The `:not` selectors end else are supported only on version `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1` and later